# Actionscript3: importing math class into as file

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to import math class to my main class that I am working on. Im trying to use math.floor() method and I just cant find it!
apparently its in Top Level Package, how can I import that?
I want to use it in an outside class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that is required... Are you using a syntax checker? Have you tried "Math.floor()" instead of "math.floor()".